# application error on google app engine launcher

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am getting this error while running an application on google app engine launcher. This is the error i am getting. I have tried reinstalling but it didnt solve the error. Please tell me where i am going worng?!

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> Python 2.7.3: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
Sun Dec 02 11:43:06 2012
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _HandleRequest(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>)
   2988         outfile = cStringIO.StringIO()
   2989         try:
=> 2990           self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
   2991         finally:
   2992           self.module_manager.UpdateModuleFileModificationTimes()
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>, self._Dispatch = <bound method DevAppServerRequestHandler._Dispat...v_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>>, dispatcher = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object>, self.rfile = <socket._fileobject object>, outfile = <cStringIO.StringO object>, env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.7.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8081', ...}
 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>, dispatcher=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object>, socket_infile=<socket._fileobject object>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.7.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8081', ...})
   2857           dispatcher.Dispatch(app_server_request,
   2858                               outfile,
=> 2859                               base_env_dict=env_dict)
   2860         finally:
   2861           request_file.close()
base_env_dict undefined, env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.7.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8081', ...}
 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object>, request=<AppServerRequest relative_url: / path: main.py ...mp', mode 'rb' at 0x0342AE38> force_admin: False>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, base_env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.7.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8081', ...})
    714         forward_request = dispatcher.Dispatch(request,
    715                                               outfile,
=>  716                                               base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
    717 
    718         while forward_request:
base_env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.7.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8081', ...}
 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.CGIDispatcher object>, request=<AppServerRequest relative_url: / path: main.py ...mp', mode 'rb' at 0x0342AE38> force_admin: False>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, base_env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.7.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8081', ...})
   1791                      memory_file,
   1792                      outfile,
=> 1793                      self._module_dict)
   1794     finally:
   1795       logging.root.level = before_level
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.CGIDispatcher object>, self._module_dict = {'Cookie': <module 'Cookie' from 'C:\Python27\lib\Cookie.pyc'>, 'StringIO': <module 'StringIO' from 'C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.pyc'>, 'UserDict': <module 'UserDict' from 'C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__future__': <module '__future__' from 'C:\Python27\lib\__future__.pyc'>, '__main__': <module 'main' from 'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py'>, '_abcoll': <module '_abcoll' from 'C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.py'>, '_bisect': <module '_bisect' (built-in)>, '_collections': <module '_collections' (built-in)>, '_functools': <module '_functools' (built-in)>, ...}
 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in ExecuteCGI(config=<AppInfoExternal version=1 source_lang...ne runtime=python api_config=None >, root_path=r'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp', handler_path='main.py', cgi_path=r'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py', env={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~rprpfind', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'localhost:8081', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', ...}, infile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, module_dict={'Cookie': <module 'Cookie' from 'C:\Python27\lib\Cookie.pyc'>, 'StringIO': <module 'StringIO' from 'C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.pyc'>, 'UserDict': <module 'UserDict' from 'C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__future__': <module '__future__' from 'C:\Python27\lib\__future__.pyc'>, '__main__': <module 'main' from 'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py'>, '_abcoll': <module '_abcoll' from 'C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.py'>, '_bisect': <module '_bisect' (built-in)>, '_collections': <module '_collections' (built-in)>, '_functools': <module '_functools' (built-in)>, ...}, exec_script=<function ExecuteOrImportScript>, exec_py27_handler=<function ExecutePy27Handler>)
   1691         reset_modules = exec_py27_handler(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
   1692       else:
=> 1693         reset_modules = exec_script(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
   1694     except SystemExit, e:
   1695       logging.debug('CGI exited with status: %s', e)
reset_modules = True, exec_script = <function ExecuteOrImportScript>, config = <AppInfoExternal version=1 source_lang...ne runtime=python api_config=None >, handler_path = 'main.py', cgi_path = r'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py', hook = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>
 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in ExecuteOrImportScript(config=<AppInfoExternal version=1 source_lang...ne runtime=python api_config=None >, handler_path='main.py', cgi_path=r'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py', import_hook=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>)
   1379 
   1380     if module_code:
=> 1381       exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
   1382     else:
   1383       script_module.main()
module_code = <code object <module> at 034ED4E8, file "C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py", line 1>, script_module = <module 'main' from 'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py'>, script_module.__dict__ = {'Page': <class 'models.Page'>, 'PythonTerm': <class 'models.PythonTerm'>, 'SearchTerm': <class 'models.SearchTerm'>, 'Video': <class 'models.Video'>, '__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>, 'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>, 'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, 'BaseException': <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, 'BufferError': <type 'exceptions.BufferError'>, 'BytesWarning': <type 'exceptions.BytesWarning'>, 'DeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.DeprecationWarning'>, 'EOFError': <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>, 'Ellipsis': Ellipsis, 'EnvironmentError': <type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>, ...}, '__doc__': None, '__file__': r'C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py', '__loader__': <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, '__name__': 'main', '__package__': None, ...}
 C:\Users\RoHiT\Desktop\rprp\main.py in ()
      4 from google.appengine.ext import db
      5 from models import PythonTerm, Page, SearchTerm, Video
=>    6 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
      7 from operator import itemgetter
      8 import urllib
bs4 undefined, BeautifulSoup undefined
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named bs4 
      args = ('No module named bs4',) 
      message = 'No module named bs4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is trying to import the BeautifulSoup library, but cannot find it.

Make sure you've installed [`beautifulsoup4`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) in your local project path. Download the `.tar.gz` tarball, unpack it and copy the `bs4` directory to your project.

Comment: i have tried installing it, but this it is showing the same error. Can you please tell me how to install it properly, with exact download links? Sorry for all this trouble, I am new in programming! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. :-)

Comment: I was finally able to upload the application to app engine, but now it is not working. It show "500 Server error". After a little research I found that the problem is with applications runtime. It should load it 30 secs I think. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer Please help me on this

Comment: A 500 server error can mean anything; it mostly means 'things are broken'. I can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: Hey! I have updated the question. This is the error I found in App Engine logs. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @rp1995: That would be a new question. Please don't change questions, just ask a new one instead.

Comment: Okay. Have asked another question. Please visit my account to see the question.

Comment: @rp1995: The question will show up automatically in the `python` and `google-app-engine` tag lists.

Comment: I added `python` for you, to distinguish it from the java app-engine.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you please me tell me what is the problem with my app?

Comment: @rp1995: At first glance it looks like a syntax error somewhere; but I am not familiar enough with the app engine. Perhaps deploying 2.7 code to a 2.5 app engine? Someone with more experience will be able to answer your question soon enough, I am not the only one helping here. :-)